# How to put better size and pos hints with kivy

Tags: python, android, button, kivy, kivy-language

I am currently working on a kivy app for mobile. I have some Labels and Buttons and they are positioned fine, if I run the programme, but when I shrink the window, the text in the labels and buttons are going off-screen. Could anybody suggest better pos and size hints, so that even though o minimise the window they won't go off-screen? 
Here is my code:

```
Label:
    color: 1,0,0,1
    pos_hint:{ "top":5,"left": 1}
    size_hint:1,1
    text: "Which number cannot be written in roman numbers?"
    font_size: 30
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
        size_hint:1,1
        text: "0"
        font_size: 30
        size: 30,30
        on_release:
            self.background_color = 250,255,0,0.3
    Button:
        pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
        size_hint:1,1
        text: "1 million"
        font_size: 30
        size: 30,30
        on_release:
            self.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
        size_hint:1,1
        text: "999"
        font_size: 30
        size: 30,30
        on_release:
            self.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
    Button:
        pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
        size_hint:1,1
        text: "10 million"
        font_size: 30
        size: 30,30
        on_release:
            self.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four your `Label` and `Button`, you can just set the size of the text and either shorten the text as needed or expand it in any direction, For example:

```
Label:
    text: 'this is some really long text which will be shortened to keep it inside the Label bounds'
    text_size: self.size
    shorten: True
    shorten_from: 'right'
```

You can use the same properties for the `Button`.
Another thing you can do I guess is expand the `Label` or `Button` as needed, for example:

```
Label:
    text_size: [self.parent.width, None]
    size: self.texture_size
```

Here, when the **horizontal** size of the text becomes too big,the text will simply grow to a *new line*